# .git is not created

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have installed `git 2.5.1-64-bit` and `TortoiseGit 1.8.15`.

I have cloned `bitbucket` repository using below command and successful in pulling all the project into local workspace but unable to find `.git directory` and even unsuccessful after using `git-init` too.

> git clone github-url
>
> git init repo-name

I am working in windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .git folder is usually flagged as hidden. You need to make Windows explorer to also show hidden files and folders. Another way might be to navigate to the working tree root and manually adding '.git'to the path in the location bar for entering this folder.